# How to use workmanager so specific applications I want won't be killed in the background?

Tags: android, background, adb

So, I have a android 10 that kills all my apps if I'm not on the foreground of it and I just want the application to be running in the background. I read somewhere that I should use workmanager for it so is there a command that I can use?